# Add element into array of objects, then use new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, lodash

I'm loading json file from hdd then I'm adding for every object id element.Further I wanna save this array into database like "bulkCreate" not create (make insert sql query for each object) for every object in array.

```
var file = 'data.json';
jf.readFile(file, function(err, obj) {

    _.forEach(obj, function(n, key) {
        n.id = new.id;
  });

});
```

How Can I access to my edited array outside for-each ? I wanna save it then like :

```
Model
  .bulkCreate(mynewarray)
  .on('success', function(new) { ... });
```

Thanks a lot for any opinion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to call `Model .bulkCreate` right after the `_.forEach()` statement as it is modifying `obj`.

I'm assuming the json file contains an array of objects

```
var file = 'data.json';
jf.readFile(file, function(err, obj) {

  _.forEach(obj, function(n) {
    n.id = new.id;
  });

  Model.bulkCreate(obj).on('success', function(new) { ... });

});
```